# Html/Jquery Scrolling Option

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just playing around with the codes recently. I wonder how do they create this scrolling option like when I scroll down, a new div pops out and when I scroll up it goes back to the main div [Hatshop Website](http://www.hatshop.com/).

This is my main div code

```
<div class="container-fluid">'
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" id="main">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <h1 class="TradeMeIcon">TRADEME</h1>
      <div>
        <ul class="ulBody">
          <li class="liTag">ABOUT</li>
          <li class="liTag">HELLO</li>
          <li class="liTag">I</li>
          <li class="liTag">AM</li>
          <li class="liTag">POTATO</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="arrowSetting" id="show" src="downArrow.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my second div that I expect to pop out when I scroll up or down :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="ItemDisplay" style="display:none">
    <div class="col-lg-12 itemdisplaybody" style="border:1px solid black">
      <img class="homeButton" id="hide" src="home.png" />
      <div class="trade col-lg-6">
        <h3>UP FOR</h3>
        <h1>Cooking</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="sell col-lg-6">
        <h3>UP FOR</h3>
        <h1>baking</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery for the arrow button :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("#main").hide();
    $("#ItemDisplay").toggle('slow');
    $("#ItemDisplay").css({
      display: "block"
    });

  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#main").toggle('slow');
    $("#main").css({
      display: "block"
    });
    $("#ItemDisplay").hide();
  });
});
```

My CSS code:

```
body {
  /*background-image: url('../jumbotronimg.jpg');*/
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

.ulBody {
  text-align: right;
  top: 130;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}

.leftBody {
  /*background :black;
opacity: 0.3;*/
  
  height: 100%;
}

.liTag {
  margin-top: 14;
}

.arrowSetting {
  position: relative;
  top: 182;
}

.homeButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: -20;
  right: -91;
  float: right;
  height: 10%;
}

.col3 {}

.TradeMeIcon {
  position: relative;
  top: 50;
  text-align: center;
}

.itemdisplayBody {
  background-color: blue;
}

.trade {
  text-align: center;
}

.sell {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Btw I'm really new to jQuery so I hope there's somebody who can help me out with it.

Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example they are using the jQuery.mousewheel.js to detect a scroll of the mouse wheel. When that happens the height of #main-holder is made to the height of the screen using JavaScript.

This is one of the examples from home.js

```
if (touch==false) {
    $('body').mousewheel(function(e, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        if (deltaY>0 && $(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#main-holder').css('height', $(window).height());

        }
        if (deltaY<0 && $("#main-holder").height() > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#main-holder').css('height', 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hmmm...okay it looks confusing. Im going to go through it. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Here is jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/f0o1p2r7/9/ with the working code. And here is the code:

1.Firstly include the CSS code:

```
.container-fluid:first-child { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; background: #fff; }
#show, #hide { cursor: pointer; }
```

2.After that include this script:

```
_height = $(window).height();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container-fluid:first').height(_height);

    $('#show').click(function(){
        show_container();
    });

    $('#hide').click(function(){
        hide_container();
    });
});


$(window,'html')
.on('mousewheel',function(e){
    var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
    //if(e.originalEvent.lenth){e=event.originalEvent[0];}
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail || -e.originalEvent.detail)));
    switch(delta){
        case 1:
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){

                hide_container();
            }
            break;
        case -1:
            if ($('.container-fluid:first').height() > 0) {
                show_container();
                return false;
            };
            break;
    }
});

function show_container(){
    $('.container-fluid:first').stop(true, true).animate({'height' : '0px'}, 500);
}

function hide_container(){
    $('.container-fluid:first').animate({'height' : _height}, 500);
}
```

3.And finally you need to remove `style="display:none"` from the `<div class="row" id="ItemDisplay"  style="display:none">` in the second container.

Comment: Hey sir, followed exactly what you did. But here is the problem now. The blue div is on top of the page even before scrolling it and it wouldnt disappear. What am i missing ?

Comment: Which is the blue div? Please share your CSS code and we will help you.

Comment: In your JSFiddle, when i scroll down, A new div will pop out, right? Thats the div that gets stuck on the page. It doesnt disappear. I have updated my post with my css Thanks !

Comment: ahhh i got it working. I removed the position: absolute; in your CSS code and it worked ! Thanks a bunch !

Comment: If I have understood correctly you want to hide to first container and the second container to replace its position with a fade effect or ? Is that correct?

Comment: yess that is what im trying to achieve. I have a button in the first container. If i press that button it will show my whole new second container and if i scroll down instead of pressing it, it will do the same thing.

Comment: I edited the CSS and jQuery code in my post. You can copy it and get it to work with the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93393/discussion-between-viktor-maksimov-and-chocobie95).